# wifi tags - are wifi-tethering and wifi-hotspot redundant?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Are "wifi-tethering" and "wifi-hotspot" redundant?

Are there *other* forms of tethering or hotspots available for Android?

[image: image-grab for when/if tags/question change(s)]

Example question

Comment: weird. the "Example question" link shows up when editing, but not when the post is displayed....

Comment: moved link to bottom; still fails to be active except in edit mode.

Comment: also, what's up with the requirement to add the "feature-request" tag ?????

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that these are all distinct things.

I agree and disagree with Bryan's answer that "wifi-tether" can be dealt with by using separate tags [wifi] and [tether] which will work in a tag search but I disagree becuase it wouldn't work as a click tag (which is how I usually use them, clicking on a tag to get a list of the relevant posts).  I think that since wifi-tether is a distinctly different thing than usb-tether and bluetooth-tether that it deserves it's own tag.

Also, wifi-hotspot is a distinctly different thing than tethering.  All wifi-hotspots allow wifi-tether(ing) but not all wifi-tether(ing) constitutes a wifi-hotspot.  Running your phone as a wifi-hotspot is a specific function that turns it into a wireless router allowing you to connect several devices through it.

I think there should be separate tags for:

- **tether** (for general topics regarding connecting your laptop to the internet via your phone.  It would encompass all the following tags...)
- **wifi-tether** (referring to connecting your laptop to the intenet via your phone, connecting to the phone through wifi)
- **bluetooth-tether**  (referring to connecting your laptop to the intenet via your phone, connecting to the phone through bluethooth)
- **usb-tether** (referring to connecting your laptop to the intenet via your phone, connecting to the phone through usb)
- **wifi-hotspot** (referring to using your phone as a wireless access point for other devices.  Possible synonyms: wifi-access-point, wifi-ap)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *can* tether via USB or bluetooth.  But with separate [wifi] (or [usb] or [bluetooth]) and [tether] tags, that should get the point across