# Merge wifi-hotspot and hotspot tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Again two synonymous tags: [hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotspot) (x11) and [wifi-hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-hotspot) (x37). While it is clear that all wifi-hotspots are hotspots, also all questions tagged "hotspot" relate to Wifi (many of them are even additionally tagged [wifi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi)). As already said, "hotspot" and "tethering" are different issues ([wifi tags - are wifi-tethering and wifi-hotspot redundant?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/wifi-tags-are-wifi-tethering-and-wifi-hotspot-redundant)), but IMHO this does not apply here.

Suggestion:

1. merge [hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotspot) with [wifi-hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-hotspot)
2. optionally: If someone thinks there are (or could be) non-wifi hotspots, add the [wifi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) tag to the merged items from "wifi-hotspot"
3. make "wifi-hotspot" a synonym to "hotspot"

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Include the "optional" step? There certainly won't be a "bluetooth-hotspot" for technical reasons (AFAIK bluetooth would always be 1:1), but who can tell about NFC (LOL: "Come together"), or what the future might bring?

Comment: I agree with the idea of merging `hotspot` with `wifi-hotspot` as they're entirely redundant, but I'm not quite sure how I feel about which way to do the merge. Part of me thinks `hotspot` is clear enough, but if every question will also carry around the `wifi` tag then using `wifi-hotspot` seems like it would be less clunky (and still allow for future theoretical tags of the form `x-hotspot` where 'x' is some communication form).

Comment: This is also covered by the fact that `wifi-hotspot` is used almost 4 times as often as `hotspot`, so I second it. It's a 2:1 -- `hotspot` seems sufficient to me as well, but `wifi-hotspot` is much more frequently used, plus allows for the future `x-hotspot`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged these tags and made [wifi-hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-hotspot) the master since:

1. It was the more popular of the two
2. It will be included a bit more visibly (as in, not just as a synonym) in the autocomplete this way
3. If we ever need to differentiate between different types of hotspots in the future (unlikely, but I suppose somewhat feasible) then we just need new tags of the form [x-hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-hotspot).
4. I flipped a coin and that's what came up (kidding <sub>or am I?</sub>)

Comment: status-completed pls